# How to know if a task completed synchronously?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await, task-parallel-library

I faintly remember there being a property that tells us whether a task executed synchronously but my memory fails me just now. Or may be there isn't and I am mixing up the `IAsyncResult.CompletedSynchronously` with this one?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check this: [Task.IAsyncResult.CompletedSynchronously Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270640(v=vs.110).aspx)

It's description looks much like the answer:

> Gets an indication of whether the operation completed synchronously.

In order to check the property value you will have to cast the `Task` into `IAsyncResult` because the `Task` implements it explicitly.

```
bool? result = (myTask as IAsyncResult)?.CompletedSynchronously;
```

Instead of the explicit cast you can use the extension method: [WindowsRuntimeSystemExtensions.AsAsyncOperation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh779745(v=vs.110).aspx) defined in the `System` namespace:

```
bool result = myTask.AsAsyncOperation().CompletedSynchronously;
```

As reasonably pointed out in the comment though there is a gag in the current [property implementation](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs,1619). As of the first of October 2016 it always returns `false`. This is a subject to change.

Comment: Unfortunately MSDN is misleading here, the property always returns false: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs,1619

Comment: @IvanDanilov Updated the answer, thanks for the clarification.

Comment: So basically, there is no way of knowing whether a Task runs synchronously or not. As of Oct 2018, because I'm still seeing that same 'gag' implementation that just returns false.  Unbelievable.

Comment: @Triynko `Task` is a kind of async operation that is not meant to complete syncronously I think. This is why the property implementation always returns `false`. As for the `Task.RunSynchronously` method, I deem it is so exotic that MS guys do not care to pay it much of attention. Since the .NET development is opensource now you can always file an issue though. Way to go if you are actually interested: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx

Comment: @Triynko Or event file a tracking at https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/61/index.html so that others could vote for the issue to get resolved.

Comment: A Task is an abstraction for an asynchronous operation, which may or may not complete synchronously. For example, Task.FromResult does not yield, and returns a completed task synchronously. To force an asynchronous yield, you can use Task.Yield. The fact that a Task may or may not complete synchronously is the whole point of it having a property called CompletedSynchronously. The fact that it always returns false, means that you cannot know whether a Task completed synchronously or not.