# Why would dynamic fail to access Result of a Task of unknown result type?

Tags: dynamic, task

Suppose I have a `Task` variable named `task`, which is of runtime type `Task<T>`.

I'm trying to access the `Result` object of the task.

When I use the dynamic keyword like so:

```
dynamic dynamicTask = task;
object result = dynamicTask.Result;
```

This results in an exception claiming

> 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task' does not contain a definition for
>   'Result'

When I hover over the `task` variable in Visual Studio, I can see that the runtime type is not `Task`, but `Task<T>` as expected, so it should have a Result property, which should be accessible by the DLR. Can anyone explain why this error may be occurring?

The error is visible in the attached image in the immediate window.
[image]

Comment: In the immediate window, I can use `(task as Task<List<T>>).Result` and it works, proving the Result property is there and accessible.  If I instead enter `((dynamic)(task as Task<List<T>>)).Result`, I get the same RuntimeBinder exception indicating that that type `Task` does not contain a definition for `Result`. It makes no sense, because I'm not dealing with a `Task` type. I'm dealing with a derived type `Task<T>`.

Comment: Even stranger. If I create a new console application, this pattern works fine.  For example: `var task = Task.FromResult<object>("abc");  Console.WriteLine(task.Result as string); Console.WriteLine(((dynamic)task).Result as string);` runs fine and prints "abc" both times without an error.

Comment: Getting closer to an answer. The dynamic keyword is used as shown in the above assembly. This code is being called from another assembly, my Test assembly, which defines the result type of the task. The result type in the calling assembly is defined in the test class as a private class. So even though the calling code owns the class in question, the dynamic keyword fails inside the called assembly, because it cannot seem to find the type of the Result property, which is `List<MyTestClass+ResultType>`.  If I make ResultType public instead of private, it works as intended.

Comment: Meanwhile, if I create a public and private class in my test class, and attempt to dynamically access Result with either result type, it works in both cases. The only difference I can see is that one is invoking dynamic from within the same assembly, while the other is invoking it an external assembly. This seems to indicate that it's not enough for a property on an object to be publicly accessible with a public generic type. If the types of any of the generic parameters are inaccessible to the assembly the code happens to be running in at the time, then it will not be able to use the type.

Comment: Ahhh, now we're getting somewhere.  This is crazy, and of course there is no answer. "Why won't the DLR (dynamic) bind to a private type?"
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39709977/why-wont-the-dlr-dynamic-bind-to-a-private-type  Comments indicate it may have something to do with it being a private nested class (works fine as a public nested class, or as non-nested private class).  Surely this is some kind of bug or overt restriction in the DLR, possibly having it approximate compile-time semantics too strictly.  IT'S DYNAMIC.

Comment: Unbelievable fail.  `namespace ConsoleApp14
{
public static class MyTypes
{
private class DLR_Invisible
{
public string S { get; set; }
}
public class DLR_Visible
{
public string S { get; set; }
}
public static Task GetVisibleResult => Task.FromResult(new DLR_Visible { S = "abc" });
public static Task GetInvisibleResult => Task.FromResult(new DLR_Invisible { S = "abc" });
}
public class Program
{
static void Main(string[] args)
{
var t1 = MyTypes.GetVisibleResult;
var r1 = ((dynamic)t1).Result;
var t2 = MyTypes.GetInvisibleResult;
var r2 = ((dynamic)t2).Result;
}
}
}`

Comment: Oh FFS! On a somewhat unrelated note, there's no way to know whether a Task completes synchronously or not, because the implementation of IAsyncResult.CompletedSynchronously is hard-coded to return false!  https://stackoverflow.com/a/37635000/88409  That explains why that one interface member is explicitly implemented and hidden by default.